# passing argument results to discards quilfiers

Tags: c++

I'm having a simple Exception class which should only return a error message.

my .h file:

```
GameException();
GameException(const char* error_message);
virtual const char* what() const throw();
const char* getErrorMessage();
const char* error_message_;
```

and my cpp file:

```
GameException::GameException(const char* error_message) 
                             : error_message_(error_message)
{

}

const char* GameException::what() const throw()
{
  return getErrorMessage();
}

const char* GameException::getErrorMessage() 
{
  return error_message_;
}
```

But I always get the error message:

```
GameException.cpp: In member function 'virtual const char* GameException::what() const':
GameException.cpp:31: error: passing 'const GameException' as 'this' argument of 'const char* GameException::getErrorMessage()' discards qualifiers
```

But shouldn't be everything from the same typ, so therefore also my argument (typ `const char`).

I'm not sure where my mistake is thanks for any help.

Comment: Make `gerErrorMessage` a `const` member: `const char* getErrorMessage() const;`.

Comment: ok. thanks for your link. now i get it :)